# Deserializing an object - how to proceed?

Tags: android, objectinputstream

In IntelliJ, I created a Trie object and serialized it into a file called "t.txt". I moved this file into the same directory as my MainActivity.java in Android Studio, and I run this code to try to get the object:

```
String fileName = "t.txt";
Trie trie = null;
try {
     FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fileName);
     ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
     trie = (Trie) ois.readObject();
     ois.close();
}
catch(IOException e) {
     System.out.println(e);
}
catch(java.lang.ClassNotFoundException e) {
     System.out.println(e);
}
```

This gives me a "file not found" error indicating it can't be opened. However, this same code works perfectly fine in IntelliJ.

How can I recover this object from t.txt in Android Studio?

Comment: The file path is invalid. Read about storage management in Android. There is a concept of external and internal memory.

Comment: The path style you used won't actually work in Android studio.. Save to `getFilesDir()` instead. I'll post an answer soon.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative. Serialize the file to `getFilesDir()` and get it from there. This way, it would be easy for you to serialize and deserialize.

**To check if a file exists in `getFilesDir()`:**

```
boolean doesMyFileExists(Activity activity, String fileName) {
    File[] files = activity.getFilesDir().listFiles();
    for(File i: files) {
        if(i.getName().equals(fileName)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

**To serialize an object (MyObject):**

```
void serializeObject(Activity activity, MyObject myObject, String fileName){
    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = activity.openFileOutput(fileName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
        oos.writeObject(myObject);
        oos.close();
        fos.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        //Catch all possible exceptions here
    }

 }
```

**To deserialize an object (MyObject):**

```
MyObject deserializeObject(Activity activity, String fileName){
    try {
        return ((MyObject) (new ObjectInputStream(activity.openFileInput(fileName)).readObject()););
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        //Catch all possible exceptions here
    }

 }
```

NOTE: The class that contains these methods must implement the `Serializable` interface.

I hope this helps, merry coding!

Comment: Thanks for the response Taslim. I feel like I might have a fundamental misunderstanding, however. I don't want the app to save any data. Essentially, the Trie is an unchanging object and it takes a long time to make. I want to make the Trie before the user downloads the app so that all the user has to do is deserialize it when they open the app and they have this important object. Is this possible?

Comment: Deserialization is possible only when you have a blueprint of the class you want to deserialize to. Why not add a basic blueprint Java class? If you have that, you can get your deserialized object anytime you want.